# Does there exist a function $f(n)$ that will equal to $n \cdot\Theta(f(n))$?

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics

Does there exist a function $f(n)$ that will equal to $n \cdot\Theta(f(n))$?

I thought about taking $\cfrac{1}{n^2}$ and then both of them will be (for high values of $n$) $\rightarrow 0$

What do you guys think?

Comment: Try using the definition..

Comment: Absolutely false.

Comment: Why did I get down voted so badly? :(

Comment: I didn't vote down, it may be because your _What do you guys think?_ makes discussion forum, which not allowed on SE. You should have to show your research.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I see. I'm sorry, and I forgot the definition that Paolo answered, It's perfect and makes it easy to solve.

Comment: Perhaps because your only personal input is to suggest a sequence that does not fit the requirement, as looking at it two seconds suffices to realize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: $anf(n) \le f(n) \le bnf(n)$ with $f(n)>0$ and $0<a<b$ implies $an\le 1 \le bn$ for all $n$.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks Paolo!!!

Comment: I forgot the definition of $\Theta$ It makes it so easy now.

Comment: Indeed. For the record, there does exist some sequences $(f(n))$ such that $f(n)=n\Theta(f(n))$ (and the present answer somewhat indirectly points at them...).